# PHP sessions, cookieless domains, and performance

Tags: php, performance, session, cookies, dns

I'm on board with the whole cookieless domains / CDN thing, and I understand how just sending cookies for requests to www.yourdomain.com, while setting up a separate domain like cdn.yourdomain.com to keep unnecessary cookies from being sent can help performance.

What I'm curious about is if using PHP's native sessions have a negative effect on performance, and if so, how? I know the session key is kept track of in a cookie, which is small, and so that seems fine.

I'm prompted to ask this question because in the past I've written my web apps and stored a lof of the user's active data, preferences, and authentication information in the `$_SESSION` variable. However, I notice that some popular web applications out there, like Wordpress, don't use `$_SESSION` at all. But sessions are easy to use and seem fairly secure, especially if you combine it with tracking user-agent / ip changes to prevent session hijacking. So why don't Wordpress and other web apps use php's sessions? Should I also stop using sessions?

Also, let me also clarify that I do realize the server must load the session data to process a page request, but that's not what I'm asking about here. My question is about if / how it impacts the network performance, especially in regard to the headers being sent / received. For example does using sessions prevent pages or images on the site from being served from the browser's cache? Is the PHPSESID cookie the only additional header that is being sent? These sorts of things.

Comment: I have no experience with Wordpress. For my curiosity, can someone verify that it really doesn't use sessions for even as basic a purpose as to maintain a login? I can see using db storage in place of extended session var storage.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't use sessions. I know why, it has historic reasons. But I'm curious which other popular web applications aren't as well? You have got more examples?

Comment: Michael - Worpress definitely does not use sessions, unless you are using a plugin that had started a session. @hakre - Can you share the historical reasons? I mostly work with WP but Expression Engine and Code Ignitor don't use PHP's sessions either.

Comment: The only example that seems to make sense would be if a change in the session cookie or URL-based SESSIONID would invalidate a browser cache/page or file cache header and trigger a download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard store for `$_SESSION` is the file-system with one file per session. This comes with a price:

- When two requests access the same session, one request will win over the other and the other request needs to wait until the first request has finished. A race condition controlled by file-locking.

Using cookies to store the session data (Wordpress, Codeigniter), the race-condition is the same but the locking is not that immanent, but a browser might do locking within the cookie management.

Using cookies has the downside that you can not store that much data and that the data get's passed with each request and response. This is likely to trigger security issues as well. Steal the cookie and you've got the data. If it's encrypted, an attacker can try to decrypt it to gain the data stored therein.

The historical reason for Wordpress was that the platform never used the PHP Sessions. The root project started around 2000, it got a lot of traction in 2002 and 2004. As session handling was only available with PHP 4 and PHP 3 was much more popular that time.

Later on, when `$_SESSION` was available, the main design of the application was already done, and it worked. Next to that, in 2004/2005 wordpress decided to start a commercial multi-blog hosting service. This created a need in scaling the application(s) across servers and cookies+database looked more easy for the session/user handling than using the `$_SESSION` implementation. Infact, this is pretty easy and just works, so there never was need to change it.

For Codeigniter I can not say that much. I know that it stores all session information inside a cookie by default. So session is just another name for cookie. Optionally it can be encrypted but this needs configuration. IIRC it was said that this has been done because "most users do not need sessions". For those who need, there is a database backend (requires additional configuration) so users can change from cookie to database store transparently within their application. There is a new implementation available as well that allows you to change to any store you like, e.g. to native PHP sessions as well. This is done with so called drivers.

However this does not mean that you can't achieve the same based on `$_SESSION` nowadays. You can replace the store with whatever you like (even cookies :) ) and the PHP implementation of it should be encapsulated anyway in a good program design.

That done you can implement a store you can better control locking on (e.g. a database) and that works across servers in a load balanced infrastructure that does not support sticky sessions.

Wordpress is a good example for an own implementation of sessions handling totally agnostic to whatever PHP offers. That means the wheel has been re-invented. With a view from today, I would not call their design explicitly innovative, so it full-fills a very specific need in a very specific environment that you can only understand if you know about the projects roots.

Codeigniter is maybe a little step ahead (in an interface sense) as it offers some sort of (unstable) interface to sessions and it's possible to replace it with any implementation you like. That's much better for new developers but it's also sort of re-inventing the wheel because PHP does this already out of the box.

The best thing you can do in an application design is to make the implementation independent from system needs, so to make the storage mechanism of your session data independent from the rest of the program flow. PHP offers this with a pretty direct interface, the `$_SESSION` array and the session configuration.

As `$_SESSION` is a superglobal array you might want to prevent your application to access it directly as this would introduce global state. So in a good design you would have an interface to it, to be able to fully abstract away from the superglobal.

Done that, plus abstraction of the store plus configuration (e.g. all in one session dependency container), you should be able to scale and maintain your application well over as many servers as you like for whatever reason. Your implementation then can just use cookies if you think that's it for you. However you will be able to switch to database based session in case you need it - without the need to rewrite large parts of your application.

Comment: So it seems like the main concern with the built-in `$_SESSION` really is scalability and not network load. Cool. Also, the Wordpress history is quite interesting. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: No, the main concern with `$_SESSION` is global state. `$_SESSION` scales very well, [you can change the storage implementation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php), see as well the manual: [Session Handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% confident this is the case but one reason to avoid the built-in $_SESSION mechanism in PHP is if you want to deploy your web application in a high-availability web farm scenario.

Because the default session behavior in PHP is to store session objects in process, in memory, it makes it hard (if not impossible) to have multiple servers processing requests from the same user. You would only have this if you wanted to deploy your web application in a web farm environment where you have a number of PHP web servers processing requests for your app to balance the load.

So, while in-process session state is generally much faster than a database-based solution, the latter is favorable when you need to process a huge number of requests and to service the capacity a web-farm environment is used.

As I said in the beginning, I'm not 100% sure if PHP supports configuring the session state provider to be a database, or session state server, instead of the in-process default.

Comment: At my job we have a load balanced environment (called DYNOFARM) in which five or six servers share the requests. I wouldn't say we're real high load, but I use sessions all the time and have never had an issue with it.

Comment: @Milky Dinescu - I see what you're saying, and it makes sense: One reason to avoid php's native sessions is because it prevents scaling up across multiple servers without using some special tools. I remember reading about this before but had forgotten. Thanks for reminding me.